# Why is my Jasmine assertion "toBeDefined" passing when the method has not been defined?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, coffeescript, jasmine, karma-runner

I am writing my tests first, and the first test I write for a method is that I expect it to be defined. I notice these assertions are passing before I define the function. For example:

```
it "should be defined", () ->
   expect(mySvc.foo).toBeDefined() # this passes when method is not defined

it "should return a promise", () ->
   expect(mySvc.foo.then).toBeDefined() # this also passes when method is not defined
```

Comment: I am new to coffeescript and this is something I haven't fully groked yet. Some functions don't require parentheses, and some need to be immediately invoked using parentheses or the "do" command.

Comment: Executive summary: `f` is a function reference, `f()` is a function call without arguments, `f x` is a function call with a single argument, `f(x)` is also a function call with a single argument. Parentheses are optional when there is no ambiguity, many people (myself included) always include the parentheses because we think it makes things clearer (i.e. less work for humans to understand the code at a glance). `do` has a specific purpose (see the last paragraph of http://coffeescript.org/#loops) but can be used (abused?) for other things.

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up!

Answer (score 1):

There must be something else affecting your test as this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nicholas_Murray/akdkwtz0/) demonstrates that it does not pass. Is it possible you have it defined within the same scope?

// This does not pass

```
describe('Jasmine test', function() {   

    it('should should be defined', function() {
        expect(mySvc.foo).toBeDefined();       
    });

});
```

// This passes

```
describe('Jasmine test', function() {   

    var mySvc = {
      foo: "foo"
    };

    it('should should be defined', function() {
        expect(mySvc.foo).toBeDefined();       
    });

});
```

Comment: I had forgotten to include the parentheses after "toBeDefined" in my coffeescript.